# Diisable HTML text in a TextBlock-Control

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

Is it possible in WPF to spend HTML text in a TextBlock? All formatting and links are displayed automatically. I have a start page in my application that will over time make several types of texts, which different Formats. Im following an example with my HTML text.

```
<h1>Fett und schief</h1>
<p>Text <b>fett</b> und noch mehr Text <i>schief</i>.<br/>
<a href="http://www.google.de">hier</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [BasB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/668272/bas-b) already answered, you can display HTML with the WebBrowser Control.
I just wanted to add a short code sample:

**In XAML:**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="&lt;h1&gt;Fett und schief&lt;/h1&gt;" Margin="0,0,218,202"></TextBlock>
<Button Width="200" Height="30" Click="Button_Click" Margin="291,0,12,281">Show HTML</Button>
 <WebBrowser x:Name="myWebBrowser" Margin="0,115,33,0"></WebBrowser>
```

**In Code Behind:**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  myWebBrowser.NavigateToString(myTextBlock.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `WebBrowser` control, and `NavigateToString(string html)` to display HTML content.